# How to encode ' character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
function showMessage(message) {
    alert(message);
}
```

But when the message comes dynamically from the server as(example): "Men's" it doesn't work.

I've tried:

```
function myEncode(message) {
    return message.replace("'", "\'");
}

showMessage(myEncode(message));
```

Doesn't seem to work. This is a simple example, the actual code is more complicated, but essentially this is the issue.

Comment: A good read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: I assume your problem is that your server-generated code results in something like `showMessage(myEncode('Men's'))`? So your JavaScript is _already_ broken at that point - so trying to replace something _in_ JavaScript if you already have a JS syntax error is of course pointless (D'oh!). Do the escaping in your server-side code _before_ you output that value as a JS string value.

Comment: Yes, it actually comes broken from the server side.

Comment: Can't you fix it on the server? That would be more logical I think, than patching it in JavaScript. Why not use something that both your server and client can understand, such as JSON? This doesn't seem like the right approach...

Comment: Indeed the problem was server side. Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the `g` parameter, for a global replace (not only the first match).

You should also escape the slash:

```
function myEncode(message) {
    return message.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
}
```

Comment: this just replaces `'` by `'`  you need to write `"\\'"`